# Building Scala Object, Class Not Found

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea

I am trying to build my Scala Project with Maven, I have used this sample POM as a guide line:
http://ryancompton.net/2014/05/19/sample-pomxml-to-build-scala--jar-with-dependenciesjar/

But I am getting this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.organization.XXX.dataProfiling
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:195)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:122)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

A colleague has managed to build the code fine with SBT but our organization uses Maven as corporate standard. This happens have it builds the jar with maven clean package in IntelliJ's

Answer (score 0):

There are three things to check.

1. Check if you have defined the "mainClass" manifest in your POM, like the following. Your built fat jar needs to know which class is the main class.

   ```
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.5</version>
            <configuration>
              <archive>
                <manifest>
                  <mainClass>org.sample.App</mainClass>
                </manifest>
              </archive>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
    </project>
   ```
2. Make sure your main class has same package name as specified in the "mainClass" manifest in POM.

For example, if your main class is specified as "org.sample.App" in POM, your main class should have package "org.sample" and class name of "App".

3. Ensure your main class defines the "main" method, like the following.

```
object HelloWorld {

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        println("Hello, world!")
    }
}
```